# Need css/jquery help adding 'open in new tab' functionality to span tag inside anchor link

Tags: html, jquery, css, hyperlink

I've got as far on this as I can with my own knowledge and looking things up online.

I want to automatically (through jquery/css) add an icon after external links that will cause the link to open in a new tab. So the reader can click the anchor text to open the regular link, or click on the icon to open the link in a new tab.

So far I've gotten an icon in a span tag to appear after external links.

What I need is... probably jquery? that will cause any clicks on the icon (in a span tag, id="ext") to open in a new tab.

Here's the fiddle so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/christophera/c0byn9w8/32/

Goal - The regular link (anchor text) should open in the same window. Mousing over the icon needs to display "open in new tab" and that needs to be the result when the icon is clicked on.

Appreciate any help in getting this accomplished!

Chris

```js
$('a:not([href^="https://google.com"]):not([href^="#"]):not([href^="/"])').addClass('external');
```

```css
.external span:last-child {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/vvyC5JS/new-tab-60.png');
margin-left: 2px;
background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
This is <a href="https://test.com">the link<span id="ext"></span></a> and some test text afterwards.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set attribute target , _blank after add class like:

```
$lnk.attr("target", "_blank").next('span').addClass('external');
```

To click span to open link on new tab, find previous anchor tag and trigger click.

Example:

```js
var $lnk = $('a:not([href^="https://rev.press"]):not([href^="#"]):not([href^="/"])')
$lnk.attr("target", "_blank").next('span').addClass('external');
$(".ext").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prev('a')[0].click();
});
```

```css
.external {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-image: url('https://rev.press/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/new-tab.svg');
  margin-left: 6px;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="https://test.com">regular link</a> <span class="ext"></span> and some test text afterwards.
  <a href="https://rev.press">internal link </a> <span class="ext"></span> and some test text afterwards.
</p>
```

I slightly change your HTML and CSS, to give a class to span.

Note:

1. SO snippet don't allow  to open new tab so [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/f4jx810o/27/)
2. id must be unique so use class.

After discussion on comment, updated answer.

```js
var $lnk = $('a:not([href^="https://rev.press"]):not([href^="#"]):not([href^="/"])');

$.each($lnk, function(index, val) {
  $(this).next('.ext').addClass('external').append("<a 'target'='_blank'  href=" + val + " >")
});
$(".ext").on("click", function(e) {
  var link = $(e.currentTarget).find('a');
  var win = window.open(link.attr('href'), link.attr('target'));
});
```

```css
.external {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-image: url('https://rev.press/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/new-tab.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="https://bing.com">Bing</a> <span class="ext"></span> and an <a href="https://rev.press">internal link </a> <span class="ext"></span>.
</p>

<p>
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a> <span class="ext"></span> and an <a href="https://rev.press/topic/news/">ininternal link
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/bsr437mj/13/)

Comment: Thank you. This isn't working though, both the anchor text and icon open in new window. I wondered if JSFiddle just always opened links in a new tab too, so I tested on my site and get the same results: https://rev.press/test.html

Comment: Do I need to change the id in the span to a class since there will be more than one, or does that not matter in this instance?

Comment: Multiple same id violate the rule. Use class.

Comment: See updated  answer (snippet / fiddle).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help with this, but it's still not working. The intention is for a click on the anchor text for the external link to open in the same window. A click on the icon for that link opens in a new tab. So a user can select to open it in the same window or in a new tab.

Comment: Can you post  brief HTML to elaborate the case.

Comment: It's like in your fiddle, but the text 'regular link' should open in the current window. Currently in your fiddle it opens in a new tab. Clicking on the icon should open the link in a new tab. This might help: https://rev.press/temp-samp.png

Comment: See updated answer , added new snippet for required condition. And let me know it's fulfill your requirement.

Comment: We are almost there - the  only problem I'm running into now is that the url in the first new tab icon seems to be saved and reused for additional icons, so if I have more than one, they all open the first url that includes an icon. I have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/christophera/xptk1vma/11/  (bing opens in the second icon, even though the link is intended to go to google)

Comment: See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shree/bsr437mj/13/ . which solved the problem

Comment: I also update above snippet :)

Comment: Hope now, all is well.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thank you again so much for sticking this out, not the easiest question to help with I know.

Answer (score -1):

**First way**

I think you can do something like this:

1. keep regular link in one anchor tag,
2. and in another anchor tag keep the same link but with `target="_blank"` attribute to open this link in new page, and inside tha anchor tag insert the image so that clicking on that icon opens the link in new page

```
<p>
  <a href="https://test.com">regular link</a>
  <a href="https://test.com" target ="_blank"><span id="ext"></span></a> 
  and some test text afterwards.
</p>
```

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/dscmr6g7/1/

Comment: I think this (second way) will do same as 4b0's answer, open clicks on both the anchor text and icon in new window, instead of just the icon. I do need to make this all as one anchor tag, not two. But thank you for trying.

Comment: Yeah you are right, because we are setting attribute on whole <a> tag that includes both regular link and the icon. Sorry for that. Maybe then you can use the first one. This will work fine i guess.